# В чём разница между Сетевой Папкой и Сетевым Диском?

Tags: сеть, администрирование, файловая-система

В каком случае лучше использовать Сетевую Папку, а в каких — Сетевой Диск?

Отличаются ли они чем-то принципиально?

Comment: а вообще, конечно, ответ целиком и полностью зависит от того, какой именно смысл **вы** вкладываете в упомянутые термины. как только определитесь — так сразу же увидите и разницу (либо её отсутствие).

Comment: @alexanderbarakin то есть у обоих терминов есть исключительно тот смысл, который вложу в него я, и ни у того, ни у другого нет строгого определения?

Comment: ваш вопрос — сугубо и исключительно о терминологии. причём о терминах, не входящих (насколько мне известно) ни в какие академические толковые словари. соответственно, требуется расшифровка использованных **вами** в **вашем** вопросе терминов. всё.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для комментария оказалось слишком много, поэтому пусть пока повисит тут, а дальше посмотрим.

С одной стороны, [**@alexander barakin**](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/178576/alexander-barakin) абсолютно прав, оба термина имеют весьма субъективные значения, и, по сути, описывают одно и тоже. Некоторый сетевой файловый ресурс.

С другой стороны, интересен сам факт появления двух разных терминов для одной сущности. Рискну предположить, что виной всему стали системы семейства Windows, и вот почему:

В unix-подобных системах файловая система представляет из себя единое дерево на всю систему, не зависимо от количества подключенных физических или сетевых носителей. Это означает, что любая папка в такой файловой системе может быть как обычной папкой, так и отдельным физическим носителем, внешним сетевым ресурсом и т.д. Так как в файловой системе unix-подобных систем отсутствует понятие диск (оно разумеется есть, но на уровне устройств), то и причин для появления термина "сетевой диск" не было.

В Windows-системах, исторически (унаследовано от DOS), каждый физический носитель имеет собственное дерево файловой системы, корнем которого является особое имя диска (например `A:`, да, `:` тоже часть имени, это позволяет отличить корень от обычной папки с однобуквенным именем). При постоянном подключении сетевого ресурса, ему также выдается собственный уникальный корень и отдельное дерево файловой системы.

Таким образом, получается, что доступ по сети открывается для папки и, с точки зрения владельца ресурса, мы имеем сетевую папку, независимо от того, выданы сетевые права на корневую папку диска или любую из вложенных. Если теперь подключить эту сетевую папку к другой машине, то мы увидим ее как дополнительный диск с собственным именем, файловой системой и т.д. и с точки зрения потребителя сетевого ресурса, вполне логично называть это сетевым диском, особенно если учесть визуальную схожесть значков.

Как видите, оба термина описывают одно и тоже, вопрос с какой стороны смотреть, как известной притче о трех слепых мудрецах и слоне.

---

Справедливости ради, надо заметить, что начиная с Windows XP, если меня не подводит память, появилась возможность монтировать физические носители и сетевые ресурсы в виде папок к файловой системе другого физического носителя, например системного. Но эта возможность почти не используется на практике, и вносит больше путаницы, чем реальной пользы, особенно с учетом того, что система не предлагает сделать это по умолчанию и в логику "click Next", характерную для семейства Windows, не укладывается совсем никак.

---

Небольшое уточнение, чтобы исключить возможное недопонимание. Термин "Файловая система" может рассматриваться в двух аспектах:
1. Способ организации хранения данных(файлов) на физическом носителе, в этом случае мы имеем множество различных решений: NTFS, FAT, EXT2/3/4, HPFS, CDFS и т.д. На этом уровне ядро ОС взаимодействует с соответствующими драверами. Этот уровень взаимодействия хоть и виден пользователю, и, в некоторых случаях, он может влиять на выбор конкретной реализации файловой системы для конкретного носители или его раздела, но критически важным он является только для самой ОС, прикладное ПО на этом уровне не работает.
2. Представление содержимого файловых носителей в структурированном виде и унификация операций чтения-записи файлов. Именно на этом уровне взаимодействует пользовательская оболочка ОС, системное и прикладное ПО. Это уровень виден пользователю, и именно на нем есть существенные видимые отличия между последователями UNIX и DOS.

Есть еще много узко-специализированных вычислительных систем и соответствующих им ОС, где может не быть ни одного решения, хотя бы отдаленно, напоминающего описанное выше.

Comment: "В unix-подобных системах файловая система представляет из себя единое дерево на всю систему, не зависимо от количества подключенных физических или сетевых носителей." - ну как единое, если оно может содержать логические разделы со своими файловыми системами?

Comment: @DukeSpontaneous уровнем ниже - да. Диски, разделы на дисках и россыпь файловых систем под конкретные задачи. Но для пользователя - файловая система выглядит как дерево с единым корнем, что и является принципиальным отличием от наследников DOS

Comment: @DukeSpontaneous добавил уточнение про "разные файловые системы на одном диске"

Comment: @DukeSpontaneous в unix-подобных разные файловые системы спокойно вкладываются друг в друга при монтировании -- вложенная файловая система перекрывает папку (точку монтирования) наружной. Особенно это заметно, если использовать FUSE, т. к. папка перекрывается только у того пользователя, кто осуществил монтирование.

Answer (score 2):

Для Windows.

Сетевая папка -- каталог файловой системы, к которому явным образом разрешен доступ по сети.

Т.е. правой кнопкой в проводнике, выбрали папку, щелкаем <kbd>Свойства</kbd>-<kbd>Доступ</kbd> и разрешаем сетевой доступ. Теперь эта папка сетевая. Причём, имя *сетевой папки* может отличаться от имени каталога файловой системы.

Сетевой диск -- постоянная связь с сетевой папкой. Чаще всего, данной связи присвоена определенная буква, как локальному физическому диску.

Т.е.в "<del>Мой</del> компьютер" нажимаем <kbd>Подключить сетевой диск</kbd>, выбираем букву для *сетевого диска* и путь к *сетевой папке*, с которой будет связан этот диск.

Comment: В общем механизмы взаимодействия с "сетевыми дисками" в Windows ничем не отличаются от механизмов взаимодействия с "сетевыми папками"?

Comment: А каких механизмах вы спрашиваете? Ну с дисками сможет обращаться любая программа, которая может работать с путями файловой системы вида `Z:/1.txt`, в то время как некоторые программы не смогут работать с путями `\\remotehost\\netfolder`

Comment: Я имел в виду такие особенности взаимодействия, как скорость передачи данных, возможность создавать символические ссылки и тому подобное.